# How can you tell if a while loop will not terminated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how exactly will you know if it will not terminate? is there a function that makes it keep on going? If i want to stop the loop after a certain number of times, how would i do it?

Comment: `while cnt < 10:` does the trick

Comment: @TJD -- What do you mean?  Taht will loop infinitely (or no times) if you don't do anything with `cnt` inside the loop.  If you really want to iterate a certain number of times use `xrange` or `range` with `for`...

Answer (score 9):

Generally, it's impossible to know ahead of time whether a program will loop forever or eventually stop. This is called the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Of course, in practice you can probably make a reasonable guess just by looking at the condition.

a while loop will keep going as long as its condition is true. You do not need a function to make it keep going.

```
while True:
    print "hello, world!"
    #no functions required here!
```

If you want something to loop a certain number of times, it's preferable to use a for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "hello, world!"
    #prints ten times
```

although you still can use a while loop if you really want.

```
count = 0
while count < 10:
    print "hello, world!"
    count += 1
```

Comment: I might even go as far as `for _ in range(10):` to make it explicit that the argument isn't going to be used, but that's just a matter of style (+1).  Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop is terminated

- if the condition it uses is false at the time it gets evaluated.

  Example:

  ```
  x = 10
  while x > 5:
      x -= 7
      print x
      x += 6
      print x
  ```

  successively will print the numbers 3, 9, 2, 8, 1, 7, 0, 6, -1, 5 and only then terminate.

  `x` becomes `<= 5` during execution, but only the state at the time where the loop is restarted is relevant.
- if it is left meanwhile with `break`:

  ```
  x = 10
  while x > 5:
      print x
      x -= 1
      break
  ```

  only prints 10, because it is left "forcefully" afterwards.

A loop which runs a certain number of times would be done

```
x = 0
while x < n:
    do_stuff()
    x += 1
```

or better with for:

```
for x in range(n):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: There is a third option you forgot: executing a return statement.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Right, or an exception, or a `sys.exit()` or `sys._exit()`.

Comment: Technically, `sys.exit()` raises a `SystemExit` exception.

Comment: mm, right. So read the above as "Right, or an exception, or a `sys._exit()`."